# Empty div (with style: height) will not display

Tags: html, css

*Incredibly* simple piece of HTML - but not displaying how I would expect.

I'm trying to create an empty div that displays as whitespace on the top of the page, with `style="height: 400px;"`

Even though I have specified a height, my empty div will not display. What am I missing here?

**UPDATE: my main question is:  Why does an empty div not display even if it has a height set? Or, what are the basic `style` rules needed to display an empty div?**

Full code:

```
<html>
<head><title>Site Name</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="height:400px; width:100%; margin:0; padding:0; position:absolute;"></div>
<div style="width: 50%; margin: auto;">
<img src="logo.gif"></div> 

<div style="width: 50%; margin: auto;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try adding display:block;

Comment: What are you expecting to see?

Comment: I made this fiddle and added borders to your divs. What are you expecting? http://jsfiddle.net/KyQgg/4/

Comment: @rosscowar I want the first div `div style="height:400px; width:100%; margin:0; padding:0; position:absolute;"` to display. Essentially I'm trying to really quickly create whitespace.

Comment: Well if you see in the fiddle, it is displaying. If you want white space for that other div consider adding, margin-top:400px;

Comment: It of course **does** display. You just took it out of the flow by using `position: absolute` which means it no longer affects the position of other elements. Aside from that, you have an unclosed `div`. That **must** be fixed.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you just want to add white space try this

```
<div style="height:400px; width:100%; clear:both;"></div>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/YCHE4/)

or you could just add padding to the body like `body { padding-top: 400px; }`

Comment: Doesn't work if you use `height: 50%`. How to make it work?

Answer (score 37):

The css style you are looking for is `min-height: 20px;` By default a div without content will have a height of 0 due to the auto setting being the default which sizes itself to fit content.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That is a brilliant solution!

Comment: This is a fix for minimum vertical height. Responsiveness usually involves setting an width/arrangement for components based on different viewport sizes.

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what outcome you're looking for. Please provide more information on the specific problem and use case you're looking to solve. Not sure why you'd need many media queries, and why you think that this needs to be responsive.

Answer (score 7):

For who looking for a white space (not exactly an empty div) you can add an empty **span** so the div is no more considered as empty one.

Avoid using `&nbsp;` because the default `font-size` can make the div higher than you want.

```css
div{
    height:100px;
    background:#ff8800;
}
```

```html
<div><span></span></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a background so you can see the white box.

```
background-color:black;
```

You won't be able to see it.

Answer (score 3):

The reason it did not display is because you had `position:absolute` in your style. That means that `div` will be positioned independently of the other elements, and have no effect on the `div` that follows. So your second `div` is essentially the first `div` on the screen.

Comment: This is the actual reason the original example wasn't working. Removing position: absolute makes example work.

Answer (score 1):

Add some whitespace to your div and it will work.

```
<div style="height:400px; width:100%">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: As mentioned in one of the other answers: "Avoid using &nbsp; because the default font-size can make the div higher than you want."