# Height of a portal is 0 - React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to measure the height of an element before it even renders on the dom. I have the below `mesureElement()` function that gives me only the width(browser width) and the height always as 0.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const containerStyle = {
    overflow: "hidden",
    display: "inline-block"
};

const measureElement = () => {
    const container = document.createElement("div");
    container.style = containerStyle;
    document.body.appendChild(container);

    ReactDOM.createPortal(<div style={{ height: "500px" }} />, container);
    const height = container.clientHeight;
    const width = container.clientWidth;

    console.log(width); // browser width
    console.log(height); // 0

    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(container);

    return { height, width };
};

export default measureElement;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Empty div (with style: height) will not display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994830/empty-div-with-style-height-will-not-display) - *edit*: actually, this one seems to be a different issue...

Comment: @Aprillion My question is not a duplicate. I have tried with the suggested answer in the question and it won't work either.

Answer (score 0):

`ReactDOM.createPortal()` works as expected only inside render methods.

Try `ReactDOM.render` instead:

```
const measureElement = () => {
  const container = document.createElement("div");
  //container.style = containerStyle;
  document.body.appendChild(container);

  //ReactDOM.createPortal(<div style={{ height: "500px" }} />, container);
  ReactDOM.render(<div style={{ height: "500px" }} />, container);
  const height = container.clientHeight;
  const width = container.clientWidth;

  console.log(width); // browser width
  console.log(height); // should be 500

  ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(container);

  return { height, width }; 
};
```

Also you can't apply styles to the HTMLElement in this way:

```
const container = document.createElement("div");
container.style = containerStyle;
```

[`HTMLElement.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) is a read-only property;